# Error initializing Neural Net object with constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, neural-network

I would like to know why I get the following error in:

Main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    vector<unsigned> topology = {3, 2, 1};
    Net (topology);

    /* more code */
}
```

Net.h

```
class Net {

public:
    Net(const std::vector<unsigned> &topology);
}
```

Error :

```
Main.cpp:18:10: error: redefinition of 'topology' with a different type: 'Net' vs 'vector<unsigned int>'
    Net (topology);
         ^
Main.cpp:17:22: note: previous definition is here
    vector<unsigned> topology = {3, 2, 1};
                     ^
1 error generated.
```

The error is fixed if in main, instead of :

```
Net (topology);
```

I use something like:

```
Net net(topology);
```

I know that make much more sense to create a variable to use, but if for some reason I want to create for example a vector< Net > I would like to do something like v.push_back(Net(topology)). Someone would know the reason of this error ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Net (topology);
```

Here you create a `Net` by the name of `topology`. I can see that you tried to make an anonymous `Net` with `topology` as constructor argument, but parentheses aren't that powerful. They're effectively ignored here.

Give your new `Net` a name, so that the parser understands what you mean:

```
Net myNet(topology);
```

In an expression context, it would work already; so, if you were to write `v.push_back(Net(topology))` as you propose then it would work, so you might have actually tried that before asking.

Comment: Thank you so much, indeed I've tried creating the vector and using the push_back() and it works fine in that scenario, I was just confused why in the declaration wasn't working, but now I understand that the parser was confusing that with a variable name since it ignored the parenthesis. Thank you!!